# What parameters should be searched with grid search

Tags: neural-network

In neural networks exist the  parameters
lr, error, iterations.

I used [this Library](https://github.com/cazala/synaptic/wiki/Trainer) in my code:

```
trainer.train(trainingSet, {
            rate: getParametersAnn(tipo,parametros).lr,//0.003
            iterations: 20000,
            error:getParametersAnn(tipo,parametros).error,//0.005
            shuffle: true,
            log: 10,
            cost: synaptic.Trainer.cost.CROSS_ENTROPY,
```

it is recommended that lr be too small to settle in the solution
[image]

what parameters should be searched with grid search?

or should I use the default parameters of the library?

with this parameters

```
rate: 0.001,
            iterations: 2000,
            error: 0.1,
            shuffle: true,
            log: 1,
            cost: synaptic.Trainer.cost.CROSS_ENTROPY
```

the result is:

```
iterations 1 error 0.5826960676804478 rate 0.001
iterations 2 error 0.24274412100103793 rate 0.001
iterations 3 error -0.1024786307448624 rate 0.001
iterations 1 error 0.5714651392530429 rate 0.001
iterations 2 error 0.30301059323863505 rate 0.001
iterations 3 error 0.062228013069539526 rate 0.001
```

.
.
.etc.

and with

```
rate: 0.1,
iterations: 20,
error: 0.1,
shuffle: true,
log: 1,
cost: synaptic.Trainer.cost.CROSS_ENTROPY

iterations 1 error -7.352525710025565 rate 0.1
iterations 1 error -11.137117275284693 rate 0.1
iterations 1 error -8.64864011321306 rate 0.1
iterations 1 error -11.165450848337727 rate 0.1
iterations 1 error -11.087407126740619 rate 0.1
iterations 1 error -11.157093359867917 rate 0.1
iterations 1 error -11.139330057051765 rate 0.1
iterations 1 error -11.111847588899709 rate 0.1
```

see the iterations of the second example, it does not advance because, how should the iterations be?

Comment: OP is in chat, feel free to give them input there: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65541/data-science-se (but answer here!)

Comment: I think this could be a good question but needs to be narrowed down to a specific modeling problem. That determines what params we are even talking about. What have you tried? what worked and didn't work?

Comment: @SeanOwen i edited my question.